# Transaction error: Failed to get height

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, vpn

When trying to send a transaction from the Monero GUI wallet, I keep getting an error `Failed to get height`. OS is latest Linux Mint, the wallet GUI version is: 0.17.2.3-113efbf (Qt 5.15.2), Embedded Monero version: 0.17.2.3-release, wallet mode: Advanced mode (Remote node).

Update: I have just changed my VPN connection's location from Switzerland to UK and the transaction is now working. Could the problem have been be this in some way?

Answer (score 1):

> Could the problem have been be this in some way?

Yes. You're using a remote node which you'll need a good connection to.